# Connecting to server over RCON

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Why does this code return what I need:

test2.py

```
import socket

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.connect(("192.168.0.101", 28960))
    sock.send(b"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFrcon xxxxxxxxx status")
    print (sock.recv(65565))
    sock.close()
```

Desired Output:

```
 b'\xff\xff\xff\xffprint\nmap:mp_rust\nnum score ping guid name lastmsg address qport rate\n

--- ----- ----  -------------------------------- --------------- ------- --------------------- ----- -----\n\n\x00'
```

but this code always returns:

```
b'\xff\xff\xff\xffdisconnect\x00'
```

**My Code**

test.py

```py
import socket
from models import RconConnection

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connection = RconConnection("192.168.0.101", 28960)
    connection.connect()
    connection.auth("xxxxxxxx")
    connection.send("status")
    print(connection.response(128))
```

models.py

```py
import socket

class RconConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    def connect(self):
        self.socket.connect(("%s" % (self.ip), self.port))
        return 1

    def auth(self, password):
        string = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFrcon_password %s" % (password)
        self.socket.send(bytearray(string, "utf-8"))
        return 1

    def send(self, command):
        string = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFrcon %s" % (command)
        self.socket.send(bytearray(string, "utf-8"))
        return 1

    def response(self, size):
        string = self.socket.recv(size)
        return string
```

Test2.py and (test.py + models.py) don't run at same time. Where the difference between test2.py and it OO-realization in test.py and models.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems both the sockets are trying to send data once the connection is established.

```
...
sock.connect(("192.168.0.101", 28960))
sock.send(b"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFrcon xxxxxxxxx status") # here
...
```

And

```
...
connection.connect()
connection.auth("xxxxxxxx") # here
connection.send("status")   # and here!
...
```

Make one/both of the receive/send the data when the other is doing the opposite, like I have done for the client socket below (so that no changes have to be made to the Rcon calls)...

```
import socket

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.connect(("192.168.0.101", 28960))
    auth = sock.recv()   # recieve "xxxxxxxx" (auth)
    status = sock.recv() # recieve "status" 
    sock.send(b"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFrcon xxxxxxxxx status")
    sock.close()
    print "Auth:", auth
    print "Status:", status
```

Comment: No, i think that you dont understand conditions of my  question